# unable to extract jdk7 in parent directory

Tags: java, tar

I want to install jdk7 in my ubuntu so i tried with this command

```
sudo tar -zxf jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz -c /opt/jdk
```

but it shown an error message:

```
tar (child): jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

what should i do to extract my jdk7 in root directory?

Comment: Are you on the same directory where the `jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz` file is?

Comment: first use `ls` to see file in current directory...

Answer (score 1):

Open a new terminal and find the file:

```
sudo updatedb && locate -b jdk-7u79-linux-x64
```

it will return the full path, for example:

```
/home/zanna/Downloads/jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz
               ^
```

Whatever the parent directory of the file is, you need to `cd` there. In my example, it is `/home/zanna/Downloads` also known as `~/Downloads` so I would do

```
cd Downloads
```

(or `cd ~/Downloads` or `cd /home/zanna/Downloads`)

Now you can untar, but you need to use `-C` not `-c` to specify the output directory (`-c` is create an archive). You must also specify a directory that exists so create the directory first (you will get a harmless error if it already exists)

```
sudo mkdir /opt/jdk
sudo tar zxf jdk-7u79-linux-x64 -C /opt/jdk
```